# Understanding why $E(\alpha)$ is a splitting field for $F(\alpha)$ when $E$ is for $F$.

Tags: field-theory

Why if $E$ is a splitting  field of a polynomial $f$ over $F$ and $\alpha$ in some extension of $F$ then $E(\alpha)$ is a splitting field of $f$ over $F(\alpha)$?

The argument that justifies the above is the following, which I cannot fully understand.

Since $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$, it is generated over $F$ by the roots of $f$.
Consequently, $E(\alpha)$ is generated by the roots as an extension of $F(\alpha)$, so $E(\alpha)$ is the splitting field
of $f$ over $F(\alpha)$.

I know when $[K(\beta):K]=\text{deg}(\text{Irr}_{\beta,K}(x)=n$ with $\text{Irr}_{\beta,K}(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K$ then $\left\{1,\beta,\beta^2,\ldots, \beta^{n-1}\right\}$ is a basis for $K(\beta)$ over $K$. This implies that $K(\beta)$ is generated by roots of $\text{Irr}_{\beta,K}(x)$  which is the argument used in the topic. However, in the case of the topic, $f(x)$ is not necessarily an irreducible polynomial (and therefore it is not the minimal polynomial).

Why if $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$, it is generated over $F$ by the roots of $f$.?

Comment: Your fourth paragraph about irreducible polynomials is completely irrelevant: the concept of a splitting field over $F$ makes sense for *all* nonconstant polynomials in $F[x]$.  If $f(x)$ is (monic and) nonconstant in $F[x]$ and $E = F(r_1, \ldots, r_n)$ where $f(x) = \prod (x - r_i)$ then $E(\alpha) = F(\alpha)(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$, so $E(\alpha)$ is generated over $F(\alpha)$ by a full set of roots of $f(x)$.  Thus $E(\alpha)$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F(\alpha)$. Nobody cares if $f(x)$ is or is not irreducible over $F$ or any other field.  What step there don't you understand?

Comment: In your fourth paragraph you make one claim that appears mistaken: you write "this implies that $K(\beta)$ is generated by roots of ${\rm Irr}_{\beta,K}(x)$". Try $K = \mathbf Q$, $f(x) = x^3 - 2$, and $\beta = \sqrt[3]{2}$. Are you saying $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is generated by the roots of $x^3 - 2$?  That field has only one root of $x^3-2$, not all of them. It is generated by *one* root of $x^3-2$, not "roots". Powers of a root of a polynomial are not also roots of the polynomial except in very special situations (e.g., powers of a root of unity).

Comment: All right. I had not read that the definition of splitting field requires that
$E=F(r_1,\ldots r_n)$
I got it, thanks.

Comment: You had written in your post "Since $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $F$, it is generated over $F$ by the roots of $f$" and that is *exactly* what it means to say $E = F(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$, where $f(x) = \prod (x - r_i)$. What had you thought the definition of a splitting field means?

Comment: That same one. I already understood. The proof would be the following:
$K=F(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ implies $K(\alpha)=F(\alpha)(r_1,\ldots, r_n)$
and $r_i\in K\subset K(\alpha)$
Therefore $K(\alpha)$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F(\alpha).$

Comment: Oh, you had written in a comment above that you "had not read that the definition of splitting field requires that  $E = F(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$," so I was wondering what you had thought being a splitting field requires.